# using an integer number as the outstream file name?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to write an mpi program where each node knows its own `rank`, which is an integer.

I this program I hope each node to create a `.txt` file with its `rank` as the file name. That is, I hope the program to generate a file called `rank.txt` where rank is an integer.

I know how to convert an `int` to `string`, but I am quite confused about how I can combine that string with `.txt` and put it into a filename. What is the easiest way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have combined the number with `.txt` and put them into a string `filename` but when I typed     `std::ofstream out_stream(filename)` the compiler tells me that

```
no matching constructor for initialization `std::outstream`
```

How can I put the string into a filename?

Comment: Are you just missing a `filename.c_str()` call? It might help if you had shared some of your code!

Comment: Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream). You need `filename.c_str()` or C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there's no constructor for `std::ofstream` that takes a `std::string`. You need to pass `const char*`, so just say:

```
std::ofstream out_stream(filename.c_str());
```

Things have changed with the latest standard revision, though, so check your compiler documentation for how to enable C++11.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already converted the `int` to an `std::string`, say `rank_s`, then `rank_s + ".txt"` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks larsmans, but can you take a look at my new edit, and teach me how I can put that string into a outstream filename?

Answer (score 1):

use fstream and the << operator.
For string concatenation:

```
 std::stringstream vIndex; 
 vIndex << i;  
 std::string index = vIndex.str() + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use boost:

```
std::string filename = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(rank) + ".txt";
```

Otherwise (for example):

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << rank;
std::string filename = s.str() + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string filename = std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
```

Needs an up to date compiler that supports c++11 for this

edited to answer question :-

If you have c++11 just do

```
std::ofstream out_stream(std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
```

If you don't then you're best looking at the other answers

Comment: "I know how to convert an int to string, but..."

Comment: Thank you J99, but can you take a look at my new edit? I'm not sure how I can put that string into a outstream filename...